# Adding jQuery to my Javascript File

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm kind of a jQuery noob. I built a chrome extension and it's working flawless when I paste the whole code to the console in Chrome. But when I try to pack it and upload it as an extension it is giving me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I know that I have to add the jQuery file as jquery.js I have it in my upload folder. I also wrote `$( document ).ready(function() {.......MYCODE.....});` to my main javascript file. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You need to add it in your document too!

Comment: use $.noConflict(); above the document.ready function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your jQuery before adding your js file.

Then the file flow should be,

1. jQuery file.
2. Your custom JS file.

If my above statement is already true, then replace '$' with 'jQuery' and try.

Comment: What do you mean by file flow?

Comment: Order. You need to add jQuery first. Then the your custom js file.